# simpleLightbox is not a function - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use [simpleLightbox](https://simplelightbox.com/) in my project, i installed it via:

> npm install simplelightbox

and my html structure is like this:

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
        <img class="image" src="../../../../assets/images/sample/book.png" alt="">
        <img class="image" src="../../../../assets/images/sample/book.png" alt="">
        <img class="image" src="../../../../assets/images/sample/book.png" alt="">
        <img class="image" src="../../../../assets/images/sample/book.png" alt="">
</div>
```

When I try to initialise lightbox in my `main.js` file, i get an error that its not a function. I try to do it like the documentation says:

```
var lightbox = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox(options);
```

Anyone has an advice?

Comment: Where are you importing the simpleLightbox script?

Comment: @JacobHeater ah... that was the issue.. but still not managing to make it work for some reason....

Comment: I've come up with a sample in Node using express. I assume that's what you're using. I'll post the example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example works fine for me. My setup uses a very basic structure with one image `book.jpg`, but it works, and the gallery operates as intended. Let me know if you have any questions.

Dependencies

`npm install --save simplelightbox`

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="./scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/simple-lightbox.js"></script>
  <link href="./scripts/simplelightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="./assets/book.jpg">Book 1</a>
    <a href="./assets/book.jpg">Book 2</a>
    <a href="./assets/book.jpg">Book 3</a>
    <a href="./assets/book.jpg">Book 4</a>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Node/Express

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 5544;

app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist'));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/simplelightbox/dist'));
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Assets Folder

```
assets/
  - book.jpg
```

Comment: In a seperate project, where I just load everything and create html structure = it works fine. But in my project, clicking on an image just opens image as a link, doesnt create the popup like it should.

Comment: @NemanjaG I'd need to see more about your project, including html, script usage, etc to be able to help you.

Comment: I think its an issue with how the project is loading scripts, I just got into it to implement this but probably many other things are messed up. Thanks tho